# Start Activities Randomly in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 9 Activities (It can be increased more than this not a fixed value) in my App on Click of the Button i want to start activities randomly.Like

```
Activity 1 -> Activity ->3 and so on.
```

And if the user clicks on the back button i want to finish the current activity and start again a new activity the the user haven't been visited yet ..

So how could i do this .

For random activity i have tried this way

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int x=rnd.nextInt(9)+1;
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
switch(x){
case 1:
myIntent.setClass(view.getContext(),Scrn1.class);
break;
case 2:
myIntent.setClass(view.getContext(), Scrn2.class);
break;
case 3:
myIntent.setClass(view.getContext(), Scrn1.class);
break;
}
```

But i am not getting the way how could i start a new activity that the user haven't visited yet

Comment: First extend the application class and maintain Activities HashMap with Activity,boolean with visited status  being visited in the App in that class and each time when you calling new intent  check that array if that is marked as false , mark your activity in the array as true and open new activity

Answer (score 2):

I used it:

```
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int x=rnd.nextInt(9)+1;

            switch(x){
            case 1:
                Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(), Scrn1.class);
                 startActivityForResult(intent1, 0);
            break;
            case 2:
                Intent intent1=new Intent(v.getContext(), Scrn2.class);
                 startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);
            break;


            ...


            case 8:
                Intent intent2=new Intent(v.getContext(), Scrn8.class);
                 startActivityForResult(intent8, 0);
            break;
            case 9:
                Intent intent2=new Intent(v.getContext(), Scrn9.class);
                 startActivityForResult(intent9, 0);
            break;
            }  
        }  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use SharedPreferences to keep track of started activities. For example, you can store array with class names or some unique activity's id. Before starting new activity you read array, see what was started already, choose new activity class, update array in preferences and launch new activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle onbackpress method,in method finish your present activity and call your random activity function, It will redirect..

Answer (score 0):

Keep a arraylist which keeps the activities number which is already launched. so next time if your random number is from that list just discard and generate the number again.

Your code looks good, you need to integrate this logic

Answer (score 0):

May be this could work for you.
Suppose there are 4 activities.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] activitiesVisited = new int[] {0,0,0,0};
int x=rnd.nextInt(9);
while(activitiesvisited[x] == 1) {
    x=rnd.nextInt(9);
}

Intent myIntent = new Intent();
switch(x){
case 1:
myIntent.setClass(view.getContext(),Scrn1.class);
activitiesVisited[0] = 1;
break;
case 2:
myIntent.setClass(view.getContext(), Scrn2.class);
activitiesVisited[1] = 1;
break;
case 3:
myIntent.setClass(view.getContext(), Scrn3.class);
activitiesVisited[2] = 1;
break;
case 4:
myIntent.setClass(view.getContext(), Scrn4.class);
activitiesVisited[3] = 1;
break;
}
```